# How to find list of databases on Microsoft Analysis Server(SSAS)

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssas-2008

I want to know if I can find out list of analysis databases on an Analysis Server by simply writing a query. I am working on SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I am sharing this information by answering my own question here cause this I found out at a [blog post](http://panigorthi.blogspot.in/2012/06/how-to-get-list-of-ssas-databases.html) and this I think is very useful for a BI developer. Following is the MDX query to get the list of SSAS databases on that server.

```
SELECT [catalog_name] as [Database Name] FROM $SYSTEM.DBSCHEMA_CATALOGS.
```

Comment: I can't the blog post, I see only a blank page, not sure it's my browser issue or the link is not valid anymore.